# In kibana, how to modify output text colour in metric visualization by condition

Tags: kibana-4

I'm using kibana 4, i need metric visualization which should provide result text in red color if it not meet my condition.

Example: if lastest update of log is not current date, it should show the date in Red color. Is it possible to add colour attribute with condition?

Answer (score -1):

Kibana doesn't support this functionality out-of-the-box. Instead, you'll need to write your own visualization (plugin). You can get an idea of how to do this by looking at the [built-in plugins](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/tree/4.5/src/plugins/). Also have a look at the [kibana project wiki](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/wiki/Plugin-Resources). (Please note that some of it is outdated.)

However, I have written a visualization for a very similar case. [Have a look](https://github.com/DeanF/health_metric_vis), I am pretty sure this will meet your needs.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.